# QGIS reclassify values error

Tags: qgis, error, reclassify

I tried to use reclassify values function in QGIS. But there are always giving the following error. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
Algorithm Reclassify values starting...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/625660db6b0d4460b378f09a2e01575e/2018NGRDI.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/lidong/Desktop/Drove data_crop height/2018/Remove_noise/2018_NGRDI.tif"
grid_tools "Reclassify Grid Values" -INPUT "/var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/625660db6b0d4460b378f09a2e01575e/2018NGRDI.sgrd" -METHOD 2 -OLD 0 -NEW 1 -SOPERATOR 0 -MIN 0 -MAX 1 -RNEW 2 -ROPERATOR 0 -RETAB "/var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/1561643514.522.txt" -TOPERATOR 1 -NODATAOPT true -NODATA 0 -OTHEROPT true -OTHERS 0 -RESULT "/var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/ae73a594010b463ba598c712a7548b96/RESULT.sdat"
/Users/lidong/.qgis2//processing/saga_batch_job.sh: line 3: 7087 Segmentation fault: 11 saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/625660db6b0d4460b378f09a2e01575e/2018NGRDI.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/lidong/Desktop/Drove data_crop height/2018/Remove_noise/2018_NGRDI.tif"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.2.3

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libgrid_tools
library : Tools
tool : Reclassify Grid Values
author : Copyrights (c) 2005 by Volker Wichmann
____________________________

Load table: /var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/1561643514.522.txt...



Load grid: /var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/625660db6b0d4460b378f09a2e01575e/2018NGRDI.sgrd...


Load table: /var/folders/zv/z59g5c7540x7nrqrk3y13tb80000gn/T/processing9c1101da7e444650846f43d22eb6877d/1561643514.522.txt...





Parameters


Grid system: 0.009902; 22555x 18742y; 109013.146251x 182362.678788y
Grid: 2018NGRDI
Reclassified Grid: Reclassified Grid
Method: simple table
Lookup Table: (columns: 3, rows: 2)
operator: min 
no data values: yes
new value: 0.000000
other values: yes
new value: 0.000000
Assign ...: NoData value of input grid





Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Reclassified Grid
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm
```

Comment: The error message says to check the log messages for more information. The log is a separate tab in the `reclassify by layer` algorithm window. Can you check the log messages and add them to your question? If you already closed the algorithm window, the log messages may have been cleared, so you might have to re-run the algorithm to get them back.